# Python Streaming pipeline on Google Dataflow missing some Element metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running a Python dataflow (beam 2.5) and was wondering why the step metrics are not showing after a `beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))`.

Everything is working fine, but the number of elements vanish.
[image: Step details for lambda]

As you can see, the numbers from this point on are zero.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Note an answer, but is there a reason to use beam 2.5 instead of 2.9?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I'll be migrating to that soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Support for streaming pipelines with Apache Beam Python SDK on Google Cloud Dataflow is in Beta](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dataflow-stream-processing-now-supports-python).

Some features are not fully supported, and that's the case for some monitoring metrics. These will gradually be added as support is improved.